# Getting FieldView From a Monadic Form or Separating View-related code from the Form

Tags: haskell, yesod

I was following along the Monadic Form example from the Yesod Web Framework Book (http://www.yesodweb.com/book-1.2/forms Monadic Forms section). The example shows how to construct a widget and return it from the form. However, I would like to avoid styling and view related code in my Handler / Form and I thought I can just get all the FieldView but I cannot figure out how to do this because `runFormPost` returns an xml (guessing that's the Widget).

Modified code from them book

```
personForm :: Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult Person, FieldView, FieldView)
personForm extra = do
    (nameRes, nameView) <- mreq textField "this is not used" Nothing
    (ageRes, ageView)   <- mreq intField  "neither is this" Nothing
    let personRes = Person <$> nameRes <*> ageRes
    return (personRes, nameView, ageView) -- my change and removed all the View related code
```

In my Handler I call it as:

```
 ((res, v1, v2), enctype) <- runFormPost personForm
```

There are a couple of issues here. (1) I get an error message that FieldView takes another parameter and unsure what it is I put `()` that seems to satisfy the compiler but I have no idea why that makes any sense. (2) Then I get the error message:  `Couldn't match expected type (FormResult a0, xml0)' with actual type(FormResult Person, FieldView (), FieldView ())'`

The second one I take it to be something related to what runFormPost returns.

Could someone please help me with the best way to get the FieldViews directly so I can place them appropriately in my Hamlet file? Or if there is a better way to separate view related items from the Handler / Form, that will be fine as well.

I did not want to use Input Forms because if there is an invalid input, there seems to be no way to trap it and handle the error in the code -- it just directs to an error page.

Thanks!